# VBA Basic Function returning null

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a very basic function that is to return symbols  such as "=", ">","<",">=", and "<=" and it is only returning a null value. any Ideas?

```
Function Lookup_Symbol(search_Name As String) As String
    Lookup_Symobl = DLookup("[Symbol]", "[Search_Names]", "[Search_Name]= '" & search_Name & "'")
End Function
```

when I do a `Debug.print DLookup("[Symbol]", "[Search_Names]", "[Search_Name]= '" & search_Name & "'")` it will return =

Comment: How are you verifying, that the function does return null?

Comment: I guess I'm not, I just assumed that it was, it may only be ""

Comment: "Lookup_Sym**bol**" and "Lookup_Sym**obl**" and not the same.

Comment: thank you everyone. got to love typos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you have misspelled `Lookup_Symbol` in your function. It should be:

```
Function Lookup_Symbol(search_Name As String) As String
    Lookup_Symbol = DLookup("[Symbol]", "[Search_Names]", "[Search_Name]= '" & search_Name & "'")
End Function
```

You would have been able to spot this much easier if you had `Option Explicit` at the top of the module; it would then have told you that the variable `Lookup_Symobl` is not defined.